# Azure DevOps Calendar - Add Event "Cannot read property 'getEnhancer' of undefined

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I installed the Team Calendar extension in our Azure DevOps Server 2019 collection and the calendar works great for me, but anyone else that tries to add an event will get a login prompt after adding the event and the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEnhancer' of undefined" in their console.

We have Windows Integrated and Anonymous turned on at the Azure DevOps site level. If it were an ntlm issue, I'd think I'd get it to. If it were a permissions within Azure DevOps issue I'd think adding them as team admins and project admins would fix it, but it didn't.

Anyone know of a way to fix that error?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the extension?

Comment: I have not tried that. I'll try and see if that helps.

Comment: That did not work. It is erroring at a different point now. Now they can create it with no bugs. Then if they try to click it to open it, they get the same error. BUT, if they refresh the page after creating the event, it works fine. They can then select it and look at it.

Comment: Actually, they've tried it a couple more times. It seems to error randomly. Sometimes on the click to Add Event. Sometimes after they submit the new event. And this is all on Chrome, btw. They tried Firefox though and it also throws that exception.

Comment: It seems more like an issue of the team calendar extension. You can [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-team-calendar/issues) for this extension on GitHub. Hope the developer will look into it and provide a fix.